# box2d b2RevoluteJoint not breaking

Tags: join, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, break

Am unable to figure out how to make the joints breakable. Basically a revolute joint is added to two b2Body with b2PolygonShape. But when a car moves on it, the joint doesnt break. Rather the car passes through the polygon shape.

Have tried the below without luck so far

```
            b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.position.Set(xPos/PTM_RATIO, yPos/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.angle = atan(dy/dx);

    bodyDef.userData = sp;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    b2Body* body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    b2Vec2 rectangle1_vertices[4];
    rectangle1_vertices[0].Set(-len/2, -width/2);
    rectangle1_vertices[1].Set(len/2, -width/2);
    rectangle1_vertices[2].Set(len/2, width/2);
    rectangle1_vertices[3].Set(-len/2, width/2);
    shape.Set(rectangle1_vertices, 4);

    b2FixtureDef fd;
    fd.shape = &shape;
    fd.density = 10.0f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fd);

    edge.body = body;

// The code below is not breaking the joint even though enableLimit = true. 
                b2RevoluteJointDef jointDef;
            b2Vec2 anchor = vertex.body->GetPosition();
            jointDef.lowerAngle = -10.0 * b2_pi / 180.0f;
            jointDef.upperAngle = 10.0 * b2_pi / 180.0f;
            jointDef.enableLimit = true;
            jointDef.maxMotorTorque = 1000.0f;
            jointDef.enableMotor = true;

            //prevEdge and edge are b2Body with b2PolygonShape.
            jointDef.Initialize(prevEdge.body, edge.body, anchor);
            world->CreateJoint(&jointDef);
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Joints in box2d are not breakable. If you are settings `enableLimit = true` it just means box2D will use your `lowerAngle` and `apperAngle` limits. There is a breakable example in box2d testbed. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying so much force to the joint that the joint anchor positions move apart, you could detect when they have moved too far and just delete the joint.